# Keyboard key stops working randomly [faced twice while typing this line itself]

Tags: linux, keyboard, debian, parrot-os

I switched to Parrot OS about 4 months ago, the first month was ok but then I started facing this issue when random keys would not work for random durations at random times.

While typing this line above, [and the title] I faced this issue again twice, in most common cases now its the Alt, S, D, J keys. These keys stop working randomly and then start working themselves again. I am not sure about other keys as I havent tried to type out every single key when they get stuck.

Comment: Have you tried another OS and checked if the keyboard works there? You can easily create a bootable live USB and test your keyboard on it. If the keyboard is not working correctly on the live OS, then it must be a hardware problem. If not, then it must be an issue with Parrot OS and I'd recommend you ask on [r/ParrotOS](https://reddit.com/r/ParrotOS/)

Comment: If the keyboard is USB: check that you have enough power for keyboard (maybe you just add devices on a low power USB port). But probably it is a hardware problem. Cleaning may solve the issue (if it is just dust), but possibly there are problem on wiring.

Comment: @SiddharthDushantha I have tried other OS'es [I do that usually] but as I mentioned, there is no specific "timing" or anything I have realised yet that triggers this, It usually happens randomly, for eg, as of rn I have been using my laptop for 2 hours and havent faced it yet, yesterday though, the first time it happened was as soon as I switched it on.